# Flash cs5 iOS holding down?

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, touch, flash-cs5

Hey, I was wondering if there was an event or something that can check if my user is holding down a button? (for iphone, iOS)

Answer (score 2):

The Event class is TouchEvent. You'll need to toggle the touch state in a variable if you want to keep the fact someone is pressing down after the fact (of the event).

You can use MouseEvent if you need/desire a single touch point. Though you still need the variable.

You need to set Multitouch.inputMode to MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT in order to turn on touch events on the iPhone. Unfortunately, you can only test touch/gesture events on the iPhone itself. (MouseEvent and TouchEvent are virtually identical in use: MOUSE_DOWN = TOUCH_BEGIN, MOUSE_MOVE = TOUCH_MOVE, TOUCH_END = MOUSE_UP. The main difference is that you can only have one "mouse" yet multiple touches.)

Personally, I use MouseEvent to test on the machine, with an if-then setting up TouchEvent listeners if Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents is true (which it only is on the iPhone/Android).

Answer (score 0):

If the button is a Cocoa Touch UIButton, you can easily connect a number of its gesture events from Interface builder to code Xcode IBActions (where you write the appropriate methods). 
[image]

How your project would connect to flash, I am not sure. Give us more details and perhaps someone can better help. ;)